# How to implement box blur in c?

Tags: c, blur

I have to create a program that applies box blur on an image in c. box blur is you get the average of the rgb values within 1 pixel away from the pixel you want to blur.

```
00ffff ff00ff fff0f0
0f0f0f f0f0f0 fff000
000fff f0f00f f00f0f
```

let's say I have a 2d array that has those RGB values of a pixel in an image. To blur the top right pixel I would have to average out the pixels in (0,0), (0,1), (1,0), (1,1) right? so for example the average is `ffffff` then if I have to blur the pixel in (0,1) would I have to use the original value `00ffff` or the new value `ffffff`???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> To blur the top right pixel I would have to average out the pixels in (0,0), (0,1), (1,0), (1,1)

That's right.

> would I have to use the original value 00ffff or the new value ffffff???

You should average the original values. I'd suggest making a copy of the multidimensional array (you can use `memcpy` to copy quickly) and then referencing the original when grabbing values.

Comment: Wow tnx for the memcpy tip helped a lot!

Comment: Making a copy wastes time. Just read the original input while writing the updated output.